# Angular - Making a HTTP GET request with parameter to Owin+Web API controller not found

Tags: c#, angularjs, http, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am trying to make  HTTP GET request with a ID in the URI to my Web API Controller but I cannot seem to get it to the proper function as well get the ID succesfully:

**angular controller**

```
  $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'api/Files/Id/' + blobId,
        responsetype: 'arraybuffer'
    }).then(function successcallback(response) {

        console.log(response);
        //logic

    }, function errorcallback(response) {

    });
```

**Startup.cs**

```
 config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultAPI",
      "api/{controller}/{id}",
      new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

**Web API Controller**

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/Files")]
 public class FileController : ApiController
 {
   //   /api/Files/
   [Authorize]
   [Route("")]
   public IHttpActionResult GetAll()
   {

   }

   //   /api/Files/Id/
   [Authorize]
   [Route("Id")]
   public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri] string id)
   {
   }
}
```

The request is returning Not Found. Is the URL supposed to be:

> url: '../api/Controller/File/' + blobId

or

> url:'../api/Controller/File/'

and I should be passing in the ID a different way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote

```
...
[RoutePrefix("api/Files")]
public class FileController : ApiController
...
```

But in your Angular Code you are using `/api/Controller/File/`

Also you need to write:

```
...
[Route("{Id}")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get([FromUri] string id)
...
```

And you don´t need to type `controller` your controller is the `FileController` and you defined the route `"api/Files"` for it.

Because of that you may have to write `.../api/api/Files/` but i am not sure about that. You have to test it

Comment: I had a typo in my post I corrected the way I am currently trying to call the controller method from the http get

Comment: I deleted the ../ with the current code I have in the OP and it still works fine, I am not sure why I was using ../ in the first place.

Comment: Ah i thought you just not wanted to show ur base url and typed ... instead :D

Comment: So just adding the {} around the Route is your suggestion? ({"id"})  ?

Comment: I thought the same... :)

Answer (score 2):

The url that you are using in the $http service is wrong. In your web api controller you are defining the routes with the following annotation:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Files")]
```

So this is the route for your controller. Try the following:

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '../api/Files/' + blobId,
        responsetype: 'arraybuffer'
    }).then(function successcallback(response) {

        console.log(response);
        //logic

    }, function errorcallback(response) {

    });
```

Comment: I think I had a typo, I typed controller when in my code I did have the correct Route

Comment: Did you remove the /Id from the url in the $http call?

Comment: Tried :  '../api/Files/' + blobId  with the controller code currently in the OP and still got not found